# Delete text in excel cell with certain format

Tags: microsoft-excel, find-and-replace

How do I easily delete strings in excel cells with certain formatting.I want to get cell with formatted string deleted like the second cell

[image]

The string could be anything the only thing that define him is formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see a way of doing it without code if the formatting is mixed within a cell. You could use a UDF like this below :

```
Function DeleteFormat(aSource As Range) As String       
    Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
    Strikethrough = True
    DeleteFormat = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(aSource.Value)
        If Not (aSource.Characters(i, 1).Font.Strikethrough = Strikethrough And     aSource.Characters(i, 1).Font.Underline = Underline) Then
            DeleteFormat = DeleteFormat & aSource.Characters(i, 1).Text
        End If
    Next
```

End Function